# Java NumberFormatException

Tags: java, joptionpane, numberformatexception

@MadProgrammer, I have used the NumberFormatException to capture blanks or characters and throw back a warning message. It was successful for the main page but for the option, "add t", instead of display each t-shirt color it loops around the first color, blue. I have also tried 'while' loop statement but it causes the program to stop. If it worked for the first part, display_menu(), I don't understand why it doesn't work for "add_t".

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OnlineStore {

    String[] ColorType = { "blue", "green", "black" };
    final int COLOURS = 3; // t choices
    int[] Color = new int[COLOURS];
    int sum;

    public int display_menu(){ // Not the main program but the main menu.
        String input = null;
        boolean test = true;
        while (test == true) {
            try {
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome!" + "\n\n1. Add t order\n2. Edit t order\n3. View current order\n4. Checkout" + "\n\nPlease enter your choice: ");
                return Integer.parseInt(input);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input must be a number.");
            }
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(input);
    }

    public OnlineStore(){ // Switch-case program
        boolean exit = false;
        do {
            switch (display_menu()) {
            case 1:
                add_t();
                break;
            case 2:
                exit = true;
                break;
            default: // If an error is encountered.
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oh dear! Error!");
                break;
            }
        } while (!exit);
    }

    public final int add_t() {
        for (int index = 0; index < ColorType.length; index++) {
            boolean test = true;
            while (test == true) {
                try {
                    String orderItems = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your t order for " + ColorType[index]);
                    int items = Integer.parseInt(orderItems);
                    Color[index] = items;
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input must be a number.");
                }
            }
        }
        sum = Color[0] + Color[1] + Color[2];
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total order is " + sum);
        return Color.length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){ // Main program
        new OnlineStore(); // Call out the program.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a quick look at `add_t`...

```
public final int add_t() {
    for (int index = 0; index < ColorType.length; index++) {
        boolean test = true;
        while (test == true) {
            try {
                String orderItems = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your t order for " + ColorType[index]);
                int items = Integer.parseInt(orderItems);
                Color[index] = items;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input must be a number.");
            }
        }
    }
    sum = Color[0] + Color[1] + Color[2];
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total order is " + sum);
    return Color.length;
}
```

First, you have a `for-loop` so you can prompt for each color type, not unreasonable, next you have `while (test == true)`, now, having a quick loop inside the loop, there's no exit condition, no where do you set `test` to `false` so the loop can exit...opps, infinite loop.

The reason it works in your previous attempt is, if no error is generated by `Integer.parseInt`, the value is automatically returned

```
return Integer.parseInt(input);
```

Now, I'm old school, I like one entry point and one exit from a method, it prevents mistakes or misunderstandings like this one.

Instead, since this seems like something you might do a lot, I'd write a simple "prompt for a integer" method, something like...

```
public Integer promptForInt(String prompt) {
    Integer value = null;
    boolean exit = false;

    do {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                value = Integer.parseInt(input);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input must be a number.");
            }
        } else {
            exit = true;
        }
    } while (value == null && !exit);

    return value;
}
```

Now, all this does is asks the user for `int` value.  It will keep looping until the user either enters a valid `int` value or presses cancel.  The method will either return a `int` (`Integer` to be exact) or a `null`.  The `null` indicating that the user pressed the cancel button

Now, you can simply use

```
public int display_menu() // Not the main program but the main menu.
{
    Integer value = promptForInt("Welcome!" + "\n\n1. Add t order\n2. Edit t order\n3. View current order\n4. Checkout" + "\n\nPlease enter your choice: ");
    return value != null ? value : 4;
}
```

and

```
public final int add_t() {
    boolean canceled = false;
    for (int index = 0; index < ColorType.length; index++) {

        Integer value = promptForInt("Please enter your t order for " + ColorType[index]);
        if (value != null) {
            Color[index] = value;
        } else {
            canceled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!canceled) {
        sum = Color[0] + Color[1] + Color[2];
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total order is " + sum);
    }
    return canceled ? -1 : Color.length;
}
```

to ask for `int` values from the user

Comment: I just incorporated your advice into my program. Works like a charm. Thank you for the detail explanation and patience. Appreciate your help. I will be more careful with introducing a loop within a loop. The prompt for integer method is really helpful. :-)

Comment: Glad it could all help ;)